# encodeURIComponent in regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, encode

I have more DIVs like this:

```
<span class="date">Fri November 9, 2012</span>
```

All these are in a var.
Example:

```
var = '
...<span class="date">Fri November 9, 2012</span>...
...<span class="date">Fri November 9, 2012</span>...
';
```

I try to replace each date with a image that contain this date.

I have this line but this didn't works:

```
ver = ver.replace(/<span class="date">(.*)<\/span>/g,'<span class="date"><img src="generateLink.php?nr='+encodeURIComponent($1)+'" /></span>');
```

My question is: I can't use **encodeURIComponent** in **regex**?

Comment: To do this you'd have to first `match` and then replace with your match results.

Comment: It works without encode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use replace with callback function

```
ver = ver.replace(/<span class="date">([^<]*)<\/span>/g,
function($0,$1) {
   return '<span class="date"><img src="generateLink.php?nr='+encodeURIComponent($1)+'"   /></span>'
});
```

And can be more simple

```
ver = ver.replace(/(<span class="date">)([^<]*)(<\/span>)/g,
function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
    return  $1+'<img src="generateLink.php?nr='+encodeURIComponent($2)+'" />'+$3
});
```

Comment: Note: It's better to use ([^<]*) instead (.*)

Comment: Had no clue `String.replace` could accept a fn as a callback. Thank you very much!